# Не могу подключить Transactions к проекту Spring+Hibernate

Tags: mysql, hibernate, java-ee, spring-mvc

Возникла ошибка при добавлении трансакций в проект. выходит следующая ошибка:

```
Info:   HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
Info:   HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
Info:   HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
Info:   HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
Info:   HHH000044: Configuring from URL: file:/D:/Developer/Programms/Chessman/ChessmanWorkSpring/target/Spring4Hiberante4Integration/WEB-INF/classes/hibernate.cfg.xml
WARN:   HHH000223: Recognized obsolete hibernate namespace http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/. Use namespace http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/ instead. Refer to Hibernate 3.6 Migration Guide!
Info:   HHH000041: Configured SessionFactory: null
WARN:   HHH000402: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
Info:   HHH000401: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chessman_work_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false]
Info:   HHH000046: Connection properties: {user=root, password=****}
Info:   HHH000006: Autocommit mode: false
Info:   HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 30 (min=1)
Info:   HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
Info:   HHH000399: Using default transaction strategy (direct JDBC transactions)
Info:   HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
Warning:   Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in com.chessman.work.settings.ConfigApp: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
Info:   HHH000030: Cleaning up connection pool [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/chessman_work_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL&serverTimezone=UTC&useSSL=false]
Severe:   Context initialization failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in com.chessman.work.settings.ConfigApp: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1631)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:443)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:325)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:5043)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.contextListenerStart(WebModule.java:592)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:5612)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebModule.start(WebModule.java:540)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:917)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:900)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:684)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:2044)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebContainer.loadWebModule(WebContainer.java:1690)
    at com.sun.enterprise.web.WebApplication.start(WebApplication.java:107)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.EngineRef.start(EngineRef.java:122)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ModuleInfo.start(ModuleInfo.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.internal.data.ApplicationInfo.start(ApplicationInfo.java:352)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:500)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.server.ApplicationLifecycle.deploy(ApplicationLifecycle.java:219)
    at org.glassfish.deployment.admin.DeployCommand.execute(DeployCommand.java:491)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:540)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2$1.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:536)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$2.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:535)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:566)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$3.run(CommandRunnerImpl.java:558)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:360)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:557)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.doCommand(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1465)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl.access$1300(CommandRunnerImpl.java:110)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1847)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.CommandRunnerImpl$ExecutionContext.execute(CommandRunnerImpl.java:1723)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.doCommand(AdminAdapter.java:534)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.admin.AdminAdapter.onMissingResource(AdminAdapter.java:224)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.StaticHttpHandlerBase.service(StaticHttpHandlerBase.java:190)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper$HttpHandlerCallable.call(ContainerMapper.java:463)
    at com.sun.enterprise.v3.services.impl.ContainerMapper.service(ContainerMapper.java:168)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.runService(HttpHandler.java:206)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandler.doHandle(HttpHandler.java:180)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServerFilter.handleRead(HttpServerFilter.java:242)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.ExecutorResolver$9.execute(ExecutorResolver.java:119)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:284)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.AbstractIOStrategy.fireIOEvent(AbstractIOStrategy.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.run0(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:117)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.strategies.WorkerThreadIOStrategy.access$100(WorkerThreadIOStrategy.java:56)
```

pom.xml

```
<properties>
<!--        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>-->
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <spring.version>4.3.20.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.3.11.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.version>8.0.12</mysql.version>
        <servlet-api-version>4.0.1</servlet-api-version>
        <jsp-version>2.2</jsp-version>
        <jstl-version>1.2</jstl-version>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>

    </properties>

    <dependencies>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring 4 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Hibernate 4 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--MYSQL Connector -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet and JSP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet-api-version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>${jsp-version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.18.2-GA</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSTL dependency -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl-version}</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>Spring4Hiberante4Integration</finalName>
        <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

вот класс:

```
package com.chessman.work.settings;

import com.chessman.work.datasource.entity.Education;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.jndi.JndiObjectFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;

/**
 *  корневой контекст для описания бинов приложения, 
 *  имеющих по большей части отношение к бизнес-логике
 * 
 * @author Алексей
 */
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class ConfigApp {

    //destroyMethod=""
    @Bean(name="dataSource")
    public DataSource jndiDataSource() {
        JndiObjectFactoryBean bean = new JndiObjectFactoryBean();
        bean.setJndiName("jdbc/chessman_work");
        bean.setProxyInterface(DataSource.class);
        bean.setLookupOnStartup(false);
        //  выяснить для чего он нужен
        //  bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return (DataSource) bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
       LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
       sessionFactory.setDataSource(jndiDataSource());
       sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("com.chessman.work.datasource.entity");
       sessionFactory.setAnnotatedClasses(Education.class);
       sessionFactory.setConfigLocation(new ClassPathResource("hibernate.cfg.xml"));
       return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory){
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
        return transactionManager;
    }

//    @Bean
//    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
//        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
//    }
}
```

Класс который при инициализации считывает данные:

```
@Component
public class ResDAOImpl {

    @Autowired
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

    private Map map;

    public ResDAOImpl() {}

    @PostConstruct
    @Transactional
    public void init() {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List<Education> list = session.createCriteria(Education.class).list();
        list.forEach(education -> System.out.println("[TEST] EDUCATION - "+education.getName()));
        session.getTransaction().commit();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема заключалась в несовместимости версий Spring и Hibernate на текущий момент времени использую:

```
<spring.version>4.3.20.RELEASE</spring.version>
<hibernate.version>5.3.7.Final</hibernate.version>
```

Советую также обратить внимание на импорт классов:

```
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean;
```

Импорты должны соответствовать версии Hibernate

Спустя 3 дня:
снова выходит. Не могу понять в чем причина.

```
Severe:   Exception while loading the app
Severe:   Undeployment failed for context /ChessmanWorkSpring
Severe:   Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'transactionManager' defined in com.chessman.work.settings.ConfigApp: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.hibernate.service.UnknownUnwrapTypeException: Cannot unwrap to requested type [javax.sql.DataSource]
```